# Sort Int array using lambda java 8

Tags: java

Just to understand `Lambda` better I have a array of integer like below -

```
Integer[] arr = {13, 7, 6, 45, 21, 9, 2, 100};
```

I want to sort the array using `Lambda` function of Java 8.
I have used

`Arrays.sort(arr, Collections.reverseOrder());`

but I want to sort it using `Lambda` of Java 8 any detailed explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Arrays#sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-) requires a `Comparator` to sort the array. You can reverse the order of arguments to [`Comparator#compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-) for the comparison to happen in the reverse order.

Without lambda, you would do it as

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] arr = { 13, 7, 6, 45, 21, 9, 2, 100 };

        Arrays.sort(arr, new Comparator<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Integer x, Integer y) {
                return Integer.compare(y, x);
            }
        });
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[100, 45, 21, 13, 9, 7, 6, 2]
```

Lambda helps you get rid of all the things enclosed by a rectangle in the picture given below:

[image]

The things enclosed by a green rectangle are not required when you have just one statement in the body.

Thus, using lambda, the code becomes:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] arr = { 13, 7, 6, 45, 21, 9, 2, 100 };
        Arrays.sort(arr, (x, y) -> Integer.compare(y, x));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[100, 45, 21, 13, 9, 7, 6, 2]
```

Comment: really useful answer, as it shows two alternatives for the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it's the `Comparator<Integer>` that you want to specify using a lambda :

```
Arrays.sort(arr, (x,y) -> y-x);
```

`Comparator<Integer>` is a `@FunctionalInterface` and can be implemented by using a lambda to define its abstract method `int compare(T in1, T in2)`. This lambda will have to be of the form `(param1, param2) -> expression that returns an int` to conform to the signature of `compare`.

The method must "Return a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.". In our case since we sort in descending order we want the smallest integer to be considered as "greatest" in the context of our sort order, which we achieve by substracting the first element from the second (if in1 > in2 then in2 - in1 < 0 then in1 comes before in2 and conversely).

You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/2ErOY9).

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the JDK Documentation :
[Arrays.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator)) :
This method accept two arguments :

1. the array to be sorted
2. the [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) used for sorting

for the comparator you have 3 choices :

1. use a separate classes

```
package com.nejeoui;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Example {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] arr = {13, 7, 6, 45, 21, 9, 2, 100};
        Arrays.sort(arr, new MyComparator());
    }

}

class MyComparator implements Comparator<Integer>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        
        return o1-o2;
    }
    
}
```

2. use an anonymous class

```
package com.nejeoui;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Example {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] arr = {13, 7, 6, 45, 21, 9, 2, 100};
        Arrays.sort(arr, new Comparator<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
                
                return o1-o2;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

3. use a lambda expression (Java 1.8)

```
package com.nejeoui;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] arr = {13, 7, 6, 45, 21, 9, 2, 100};
        Arrays.sort(arr,  (o1,o2)-> o1-o2 );
    }

}
```

As you may notice the Lambda expression is less verbose and elegant way to write anonymous classes from a [functional interface](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Arrays.stream()` like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] arr = {13, 7, 6, 45, 21, 9, 2, 100};

    Integer[] sortedArr = Arrays.stream(arr)    // stream the content
                            // sort it in reverse order
                            .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder())
                            // and define a data structure for the result
                            .toArray(Integer[]::new);
    // output the result
    Arrays.stream(sortedArr).forEach(i -> System.out.print(i + " "));
}
```

The output is

```
100 45 21 13 9 7 6 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Arrays.asList` to make it `List<Integer>` and then use stream.sorted() method to sort integer list like this:

`Arrays.asList(arr).stream().sorted().forEach(System.out::println);`

And for reverse :

`Arrays.asList(arr).stream().sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).forEach(System.out::println)`;